# no such file or directory, scandir '/sql/' issue var sql = new SQLBuilder('SQLServer'); on creating the object of json-sql-builder2 module

Tags: node.js, sql-server, aws-lambda, query-builder

I'm getting this below error on deploying my aws lambda package on node 8.10.0 but it works fine in my local windows.

```
let modules = tools.walk(path.join(__dirname, `../sql/`));
```

on logging the _dirname it was showing '/' even though its is 'var/task'
  lambda uploaded package has src
                              src/index.js
                              sql
                              sql/somemodules
  this folders and files inside the uploaded package.
 FYI: lambda package has bundled using webpack.

```
2019-05-09T04:23:22.996Z    6010d98c-2788-4c96-b972-49361876948c    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/sql/'
at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:904:18)
at Object.walk (/var/task/src/index.js:144899:16)
at SQLBuilder._loadModules (/var/task/src/index.js:144709:23)
at new SQLBuilder (/var/task/src/index.js:144298:8)
at handler (/var/task/src/index.js:76189:15)
```

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: @hsz added one line of code.